# Wanting to add a counter/streak for guessing game

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I have two files, 1 html and 1 javascript. I am trying to add a streak function so when a answer is guessed correctly the streak goes up by 1 if one question is guessed wrong the counter goes back to 0. I have tried to add a div in the html file and tried to call it in another javascript file by getting document by ID and then writing a simple counter function, but that appears not to work.

The code below is where i want to add my counter. So in the last return "Great work! You guessed the word!" that is where the counter should start counting and showing up in a div/span/p in the html file. Any suggestions?

Note the var is meant to be streak/counter instead of clicks

```
    get statusMessage(){
    var streak=0;
    if (this.status === 'playing'){
        return `Guesses left: ${this.remainingGuesses}`
    } else if (this.status === 'failed') {
        streak=0;
        document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;   
        return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}" 
        `
    } else {
        return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
        streak += 1;
        document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;   
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should define the `streak` variable as a property in the `constructor` method.

Comment: I have defined streak in the constructor method but the streak still does not go up, and also now it does not return the string for both else statements

Comment: Please share the entire class definition. Right now it is too hard to present a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `var streak=0;` inside the function every time it gets called it sets the variable back to 0. You should move it outside the function. You also return before incrementing the streak variable, so move that line down.

Like this:

```
var streak = 0;

get statusMessage() {
    if (this.status === 'playing'){
        return `Guesses left: ${this.remainingGuesses}`
    } else if (this.status === 'failed') {
        streak=0;
        document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;   
        return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}" 
    } else {
        streak++;
        document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;
        return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
    }
}
```

Also you can use `streak++;` to increment a variable by 1.

Comment: it now underlines var as an error and says it is a unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

When you `return` the following code will not be executed.

So in the following snippet

```
else {
    return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
    streak += 1;
    document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;      
}
```

the `streak +=1` and the document manipulation will not run.

Just move the `return` after the code you want to run.

```
else {
    streak += 1;
    document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = streak;
    return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
}
```

Of course, you will also have to put the `streak` variable somewhere where it is not reset on each call of the `statusMessage` method. Maybe define it in the game class.

Comment: all code after the second return became the same color

Comment: your are missing a ` after the string of the second return.

Comment: thats sorted the problem but the return text does not show anymore for both returns

Comment: @ah5ann Then there is likely an error happening. Open the console and see what it shows. My guess is that you do not have an element with `id="streak"` so your `getElementById` returns `null` and crashes when you try to access the `.innerHTML` of null.

Answer (score 0):

So i dont know if its the best way to add a counter like this but, streak.innerHTML = 0 sets the div to 0 and streak.innerHTML ++ adds 1 everytime the answer is guessed correctly

````
get statusMessage() {
if (this.status === 'playing'){
return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}"`
    return `Guesses left: ${this.remainingGuesses}`
} else if (this.status === 'failed') {   
streak.innerHTML = 0
    return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}"```

} else { 
streak.innerHTML ++
return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
}

}
````